# Can someone pls explain what I am doing wrong in my approach to this question

Tags: c++, arrays

Alice is a kindergarten teacher. She wants to give some candies to the children in her class.  All the children sit in a line and each of them has a rating score according to his or her performance in the class.  Alice wants to give at least 1 candy to each child. If two children sit next to each other, then the one with the higher rating must get more candies. Alice wants to minimize the total number of candies she must buy.

Example

She gives the students candy in the following minimal amounts: . She must buy a minimum of 10 candies.

Function Description

Complete the candies function in the editor below.

candies has the following parameter(s):

int n: the number of children in the class

int arr[n]: the ratings of each student
Returns

int: the minimum number of candies Alice must buy
Input Format

The first line contains an integer ,n , the size of arr .

Each of the next n lines contains an integer arr[i] indicating the rating of the student at position .

Constraints

`1<n<10^5`

`1<arr[i]<10^5`

Sample Input 0

```
3
1
2
2
```

Sample Output 0

```
4
```

Explanation 0

Here 1, 2, 2 is the rating. Note that when two children have equal rating, they are allowed to have different number of candies. Hence optimal distribution will be 1, 2, 1.

Sample Input 1

```
10
2
4
2
6
1
7
8
9
2
1
```

Sample Output 1

```
19
```

Explanation 1

Optimal distribution will be 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 2 1.

Sample Input 2

```
8
2
4
3
5
2
6
4
```

Sample Output 2

```
12
```

Explanation 2

Optimal distribution will be 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n],arr1[n];
    
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=0;
        arr1[i]=1;
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    
    
    for(int i=1; i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if((arr[i]>arr[i-1]) && (arr[i]>arr[i+1]))
        {
            arr1[i]=(max(arr1[i-1],arr1[i+1])+1);
        }
        else if(arr[i]>arr[i-1])
        {
            arr1[i]=arr1[i-1]+1;
        }
        else if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            arr1[i]=arr1[i+1]+1;        
        }
        else 
        {
        
        }
       
        
    }
    
    for(int i=1; i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if((arr[i]>arr[i-1]) && (arr[i]>arr[i+1]))
        {
            if((arr1[i]>arr1[i-1]) && (arr1[i]>arr1[i+1]))
            {
                
            }
            else 
            {
                arr1[i]=max(arr1[i-1],arr1[i+1])+1;
            }
        }
        else if(arr[i]>arr[i-1])
        {
            if(arr1[i]>arr1[i-1])
            {
                
            }
            else 
            {
                arr1[i]=arr1[i-1]+1;
            }     
        }
        else if(arr[i]>arr[i+1])
        {
            if(arr1[i]>arr1[i+1])
            {
                
            }
            else 
            {
                arr1[i]=arr1[i+1]+1;
            }     
        }
        else 
        {
             
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    if(arr[n-1]>arr[n-2])
    {
        arr1[n-1]=arr1[n-2]+1;
    }
    else 
    {
        
    }
    
    if(arr[0]>arr[1])
    {
        arr1[0]=arr1[1]+1;
    }
    else {
    
    }
    
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        sum+=arr1[i];
    }
    cout<<sum;
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

My Approach:
I imagine the kids being numbered from 0 to n-1.
`arr[]`(This array stores the rank of the kids and the index of the array corresponds to the kid's number)
`arr1[]`(This array stores the distribution of the candies and the index of the array corresponds to the kid's number)

All the elements in `arr1[]` are initialized as 1.

In the first loop I am using the concept of maxima-minima.

If the value in `arr[i]` is a maxima then I store `max(arr1[i-1], arr1[i+1])` in `arr1[i]`.

If the value in `arr[i]` is increasing i.e. it's more than `arr[i-1]` but less than `arr[i+1]` then  `arr1[i]=arr1[i-1]+1;` is executed.

If the value in `arr[i]` is decreasing i.e. it's more than `arr[i+1]` but less than `arr[i-1]` then  `arr1[i]=arr1[i=1]+1;` is executed.

If `arr[i]` is a minima then nothing happens and the value in `arr1[i]` remains 1.

In the second loop a similar action is executed but now I check if the values are correct in `arr1[]` or not.

If the number in `arr[i]` is a maxima I check if the number stored in `arr1[i]` is a maxima or not, if not then I increment the value to its correct amount.

I do the same for increasing, decreasing, and minima as well.

Finally I print the output.

Please explain what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Things to change in order to increase your own chances to spot mistakes: Use speaking names in order to avoid the need to write long explanations. Do the remaining needed explaining in comments, that is what they are for. Use consistent indentation. Initialise variables whenever you are not 100% sure that they get meaningful values during execution (e.g. do not trust the input). In C++ do not use variable lenght arrays, use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? What is the output of your code?

Comment: You do 2 passes though the array in increasing index order (excluding the loops that exclusively sum up or read the input). In both loops only information about smaller indices and the next index is used, i.e. after the second loop at most the information of the next 2 indices is considered. For this reason the approach you posted cannot be correct, since it would inevitably fail for an input array like `1, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1`